# In line function error

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, inline

I have some lambda functions in a python tkinter GUI. When I run the program I get this error, but I'm not sure what it means.

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-command": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, 
-ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Here is my code containing the functions:

```
self.sendbutton = Button(self, text = "Send")
    self.sendbutton.grid(row = 2, column = 0, command = lambda: self.sendMessage())

def sendMessage(self):
    print "Your message was sent."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command` should be an argument to the button's constructor, not the `grid` method:

```
self.sendbutton = Button(self, text = "Send", command = lambda: self.sendMessage())
self.sendbutton.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```

The only arguments you give to `grid` are those that control how the widget is gridded in the window.